# Advanced Cellular Automata to generate caves

Tags: c#, unity, procedural-generation

I am trying to make caves in Unity. To do this, I am trying to use cellular automata. I found the following ([Rouge Basin Cellular Automata for Caves](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Cellular_Automata_Method_for_Generating_Random_Cave-Like_Levels)) that resembles what I am trying to accomplish.

However, the tutorial is not entirely what I want. I want something like what is produced by this website([Don Jon Caves](http://donjon.bin.sh/fantasy/dungeon/index.cgi)) with the "cavernous" setting (see image below).[image]

As you can see in the image, everything is connected. I have tried numerous methods and libraries, however nothing has worked.

I have been struggling with this issue for a while, and I would appreciate any guidance what so ever.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure the approach used by the example you show, but here is how I'd probably go about creating something similar...

First, create an undirected network graph, something like this...

[image: Undirected network graph]

You'd generate it from a set of randomly placed nodes, including at least one that represents your cave entrance/exit.

Now that you have this graph, imagine if you were to first open up a set of passages along each vertex - just simple straight passages, not irregular.

Now you've basically got a cave, but with very smooth walls.  It would look something like this from the above graph...

[image: Cave lines]

So the thing to do then is take those walls and "erode" them to create rough and irregular walls.  Taking the example here, this is what you might get...

[image: Cave eroded]

And if in the process, you erode through into another hall, then no problem - you've just created a new cavern!

The original graph image is from http://mathinsight.org/undirected_graph_definition

Comment: It's easy enough to place the nodes randomly, but what sort of metric is used to connect them? Do people usually pick n nodes? Or maybe they have to be certain closeness together?

Comment: If you need a semi-regular distribution start with a perfect grid, then randomize the node positions +/- some distance. If that's not enough add some random exceptions that double the random distance.
You can add some random thickness to the connecting lines using a plasma cloud texture to pick the thickness in a seemingly organic way.

Comment: Connecting the nodes is another separate problem.  Here's one question that discusses it -> http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11962/how-to-generate-random-directed-connected-graph   Even if the lines cross, the method is still valid.

Comment: It really comes down to requirements. If you're okay with whatever, you can get this done fairly simply. If you want a complicated approach, you can even calculate a minimum spanning tree and have corridors terminate if they hit another corridor (I did something similar in a Ruby roguelike I wrote once).

Comment: I would generate this graph as a [Probabalistic Road Map](http://www.kavrakilab.org/robotics/prm.html). Start by creating a set of "obstacles" that are considered impassable. This can be done using Perlin Noise. Then, place N nodes randomly and at uniform in the free space. Connect each node to its K nearest nodes such that the connection is in free space. The result is likely to be connected, and will look very organic.

Comment: Connecting nodes could also be done with [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation). It tends to avoid making paths that are very close to other ones in angle.

Answer (score 1):

one way to do this is to group all the caves with a disjoint set and then remove all but the biggest

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
public class DisjointSet
{
    private List<int> _parent;
    private List<int> _rank;
    public DisjointSet(int count)
    {
        _parent = Enumerable.Range(0, count).ToList();
        _rank = Enumerable.Repeat(0, count).ToList();
    }
    public int Find(int i)
    {
        if (_parent[i] == i)
            return i;
        else
        {
            int result = Find(_parent[i]);
            _parent[i] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void Union(int i, int j)
    {
        int fi = Find(i);
        int fj = Find(j);
        int ri = _rank[fi];
        int rj = _rank[fj];
        if (fi == fj) return;
        if (ri < rj)
            _parent[fi] = fj;
        else if (rj < ri)
            _parent[fj] = fi;
        else
        {
            _parent[fj] = fi;
            _rank[fi]++;
        }
    }
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> Split(List<bool> list)
    {
        var groups = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _parent.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector2 p = PathFinder.Instance.TilePosition(i);
            if (PathFinder.Instance.InsideEdge(p) && list[i])
            {
                int root = Find(i);
                if (!groups.ContainsKey(root))
                {
                    groups.Add(root, new List<int>());
                }
                groups[root].Add(i);
            }
        }
        return groups;
    }
}
```

here is where i create my cellular list and sometimes remove the small ones
i combine multiple lists sometimes and also use these lists for generating and outlining bodies of water and flora (patches of trees, flowers, grass) and fog

```
private List<bool> GetCellularList(int steps, float chance, int birth, int death)
{
    int count = _width * _height;
    List<bool> list = Enumerable.Repeat(false, count).ToList();
    for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            Vector2 p = new Vector2(x, y);
            int index = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(p);
            list[index] = Utility.RandomPercent(chance);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        var temp = Enumerable.Repeat(false, count).ToList();
        for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
            {
                Vector2 p = new Vector2(x, y);
                int index = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(p);
                if (index == -1) Debug.Log(index);
                int adjacent = GetAdjacentCount(list, p);
                bool set = list[index];
                if (set)
                {
                    if (adjacent < death)
                        set = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (adjacent > birth)
                        set = true;
                }
                temp[index] = set;
            }
        }
        list = temp;
    }
    if ((steps > 0) && Utility.RandomBool())
        RemoveSmall(list);
    return list;
}
```

here is the code that removes the small groups from the list

```
private void UnionAdjacent(DisjointSet disjoint, List<bool> list, Vector2 p)
{
    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            if (!((x == 0) && (y == 0)))
            {
                Vector2 point = new Vector2(p.x + x, p.y + y);
                if (PathFinder.Instance.InsideEdge(point))
                {
                    int index = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(point);
                    if (list[index])
                    {
                        int index0 = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(p);
                        int root0 = disjoint.Find(index0);
                        int index1 = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(point);
                        int root1 = disjoint.Find(index1);
                        if (root0 != root1)
                        {
                            disjoint.Union(root0, root1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
private DisjointSet DisjointSetup(List<bool> list)
{
    DisjointSet disjoint = new DisjointSet(_width * _height);
    for (int y = 0; y < _height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < _width; x++)
        {
            Vector2 p = new Vector2(x, y);
            if (PathFinder.Instance.InsideEdge(p))
            {
                int index = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(p);
                if (list[index])
                {
                    UnionAdjacent(disjoint, list, p);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return disjoint;
}
private void RemoveSmallGroups(List<bool> list, Dictionary<int, List<int>> groups)
{
    int biggest = 0;
    int biggestKey = 0;
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        if (group.Value.Count > biggest)
        {
            biggest = group.Value.Count;
            biggestKey = group.Key;
        }
    }
    var remove = new List<int>();
    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        if (group.Key != biggestKey)
        {
            remove.Add(group.Key);
        }
    }
    foreach (var key in remove)
    {
        FillGroup(list, groups[key]);
        groups.Remove(key);
    }
}
private void FillGroup(List<bool> list, List<int> group)
{
    foreach (int index in group)
    {
        list[index] = false;
    }
}
private void RemoveSmall(List<bool> list)
{
    DisjointSet disjoint = DisjointSetup(list);
    Dictionary<int, List<int>> groups = disjoint.Split(list);
    RemoveSmallGroups(list, groups);
}
private bool IsGroupEdge(List<bool> list, Vector2 p)
{
    bool edge = false;
    for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
        {
            if (!((x == 0) && (y == 0)))
            {
                Vector2 point = new Vector2(p.x + x, p.y + y);
                if (PathFinder.Instance.InsideMap(point))
                {
                    int index = PathFinder.Instance.TileIndex(point);
                    if (!list[index])
                    {
                        edge = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return edge;
}
```

or if you don't remove small just put your stuff in biggest cave

```
private List<int> Biggest(List<bool> list)
{
    DisjointSet disjoint = DisjointSetup(list);
    Dictionary<int, List<int>> groups = disjoint.Split(list);
    RemoveSmallGroups(list, groups);
    IEnumerator<List<int>> enumerator = groups.Values.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();
    List<int> group = enumerator.Current;
    return group;
}
```

...

```
public int TileIndex(int x, int y)
{
    return y * Generator.Instance.Width + x;
}
public Vector2 TilePosition(int index)
{
    float y = index / Generator.Instance.Width;
    float x = index - Generator.Instance.Width * y;
    return new Vector2(x, y);
}
```